# Acabo de cambiar a la versión 2.3 y no puedo crear un nuevo proyectos

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-asynctask

Antes tenía la versión 2.0 y todo estaba normal solo tenia que agragarle la depencia de ***junit.junit:4.12*** y ahora me salen mas dependencias que agragar y me dice que tengo que actualizar el SDK me sale todo esto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora obtengo este error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da click en: **Install repository and sync project:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Principalmente requieres instalar SDK Build Tools versión 25.0.0 como minimo para Android Studio 2.3 y actualmente tienes instalada la versión 23.0.2.

Da click en los mensajes y de esta forma se instalaran las dependencias o versiones necesarias para construir correctamente tu proyecto.

---

En cuanto al error :

> Failed to find target with hash string android-23

, necesitas instalar el SDK para la versión 23 (Marshmallow):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]