# ¿Cómo solucionar gradle proyect sync failed en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas a todos. 
La cosa es que he descargado muy recientemente Android Studio para usarlo por primera vez y por tanto aprender. He seguido las instrucciones sobre la instalación del programa en cuestión y de Java. En pocas palabras he agotado los procesos de instalación. Sin embargo y para mi desgracia al crear un nuevo proyecto me saltan unos errores que mostraré a continuación. Espero mucho su ayuda ya que verdaderamente no se que hacer.
He intentado en dar clic en **Install Repository and sync project**, y también en dar clic en **Try again** cuando salta el error de **Gradle Proyect Sync failed** además de reinstalar el programa en sí.

[image: Imagen que muestra el problema.]

Comment: Ya le has dada a **install Repository and sync project**

Comment: Así es, pero no parece suceder absolutamente nada.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega una captura del archivo **build.gradle (module app)**. Se encuentra dentro de **Gradle Scripts**.

Comment: Listo, ahí la puse.

Comment: Solucionar estas clases de problemas muchas veces es un ensayo de prueba y error, ya que el origen del problema puede ser muy variado. Prueba presionando **Try again** en el mensaje de color crema, si es que aun no los has presionado.

Comment: Eso ya lo he intentado.

Comment: Cambia la librería de soporte de 26 a 25 espreso seguramente no puede trabajar con esta versión.

Comment: Antes de seguir realizando sugerencias, coméntame lo que has intentado hasta ahora y los resultados que has obtenido. Seria bueno que lo agregaras en tu pregunta.

Comment: He intentado en dar clic en Install Repository and sync project, y también en dar clic en Try again cuando salta el error de Gradle Proyect Sync failed además de reinstalar el programa en sí. Solo eso.

Comment: Abre tu **sdk** y verifica que las librerías necesarias esten instaladas. Para entrar al **sdk** preciona el icono de android con la flecha azul hacia abajo. Es el que esta en la barra de herramientas, al lado del signo de interrogación. Cuando entres al sdk tienes que descargar la api de android que utilizarás para desarrollar tu aplicación. Cuando entres al sdk envia una captura.

Comment: Ahí lo puse en una respuesta.

Comment: Yo intentaria con otra versión de Android Studio, he visto algunas ocasiones que no funciona bien , en algunos equipos

Comment: Esta solucionado.

Comment: En mi caso, el mensaje se desplegaba porque de manera errónea había escrito mal el nombre del paquete (Package name). Había escrito: or.example.myapplication y la forma correcta es: org.example.myapplication

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta solucionado. Descubrí que lo mas probable era que ya tuviese el **Repository** instalado y que por eso al dar clic en la opción **Install Repository and sync proyect** que salia en error, el mismo no se instalaba, así que me dirigí a **DSK manager>DSK tool>Support Repository** y ahí desactive la casilla del **Android Support Repositoy** y por tanto el mismo se desinstaló, a continuación di clic en la opción **Install Repository and sync proyect** entonces si empezó la descarga y se instaló. Espero que a otros les sirva. Gracias.

Comment: alexander-jimenez No entiendo. Tengo el mismo error con IntellijIdea y no veo en el menu de lo que hablas. AYUDA porfa

Answer (score 0):

El problema ocurre al sincronizar tu proyecto con la configuración definida dentro de tu archivo build.gradle. Hay 2 razones principales, primeramente que tu archivo tenga algún error en la configuración provocado por algún comando mal escrito o como en este caso que las dependencias definidas no se encuentran instaladas.

Da clic en

> Install Repository and Sync Proyect

Esto obligara a descargar la dependencia que necesita tu proyecto al ser definida dentro del archivo `build.gradle`.

Si este procedimiento no instala las dependencias es porque la dependencia esta mal escrita o la versión definida no existe.

Revisa esta respuesta:

[Acabo de cambiar a la versión 2.3 y no puedo crear un nuevo proyectos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70502/acabo-de-cambiar-a-la-versi%C3%B3n-2-3-y-no-puedo-crear-un-nuevo-proyectos/70506#70506)

Comment: He intentado dar clic en Install Repository and Sync Proyect pero el problema sigue sin solucionarse.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas veces, clicando primero Make project, y luego run funciona ok ya que en make project hace una sync del gradle. Espero sirva de ayuda, un saludo!